# Appending Dynamic variable value to ngmodel of matselect is not working

Tags: angular

```
        <mat-label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" >Crop Type  <span  class="required-asterisk">*</span></mat-label>  
        <div class="col-sm-10">  
       <mat-select   placeholder="Select Crop Type" [(ngModel)]="cropname"  class="select" formControlName="croptype">
            <mat-option *ngFor = "let i of Croptype"  [value] = "i">{{i.CropName}}</mat-option> 
       </mat-select>
        </div>
```

When i tried to use two way binding to bind dynamic value to ngmodel, ng-reflect-model is updating correct value,but view is not getting updated. please see the  above picture for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWpo.png)

Comment: In component.ts
  Croptype = [
    { CropID: '1', CropName: 'sweetlime', ScientificName: 'CitrusImetta' },
  ];                                                                                              
           this.cropname=newsortOrder != undefined ? newsortOrder.cropName : ''; when iam updating ngmodel value with below line the above issue occurs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be1gqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html                  The above URL contains my problem. Please refer it

Comment: What you are patching into cropname variable is not exist on Croptype array so it won't display you selected. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Devang Patel, I need to display dynamic variable value on the view of select dropdown

Comment: can anyone please help to fix the issue

Comment: @ Devang Patel-is it possible what iam trying to achieve

Comment: Cropname value inside array and your ngmodel value should be same then it will be displayed as selected in dropdown.

Comment: @DevangPatel-I changed the Cropname value inside array and ngmodel value as same. Still it is not showing on dropdown. Please consider the following URL(with the changes you mentioned)                                  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be1gqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @DevangPatel-if [value]=i.CropName and Cropname value inside array and ngmodel value are same, then it is showing on dropdown ,but if [value]="i", it is not working. But based on our requirement we need to have complete object value in [Value].so please suggest how to do this

Comment: It is not possible without doing changes of [value]=i.CropName. Whatever you will add in [Value] will be bound into your ngmodel

Comment: So is there any other way to  do this based on our requirement(Store complete object value in [Value] and displaying dynamic variable on dropdown on button click).Whether do you have any other idea in this regard